# Problems with link to eval()in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

What am I doing wrong here?

This seems to work fine earlier in my code:

```
-@images.each do |img|
          -link_to eval(params[:action] + '_image_path(img)') do
             =image_tag img.image.url(:thumbnail)
```

But this is not working. Why not?

```
 -link_to eval(params[:action] + '_image_path(@featured_image)') do
    =image_tag @featured_image.image.url(:display)
```

I am seeing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined" There seems to be an issue with calling _image_path(@featured_image)'. :(

Comment: This seems like a possible code injection vector. For example, if I somehow manage to make the action be `system('rm -rf ~')#`, you've lost your app. Even if not, just for the performance implications, a better way would be `send("#{action}_image_path", img)`.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure how this answers my question.. but thanks. The first part works fine, the second snippet of code doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `@featured_image` is undefined? That seems like what's happening here.

Comment: Well it can't be undefined because =image_tag @featured_image.image.url(:display) in the next line is causing it to display correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm lost as to what's breaking, then - I'd check to see if params[:action] or your _image_path route is undefined, in that case - it sounds like one of your variables is empty, but my first guess would have been that it was `@featured_image`.